# COLUMN_NAME loop Oracle Database

Tags: java, database-metadata

I have some problems with my code. I want to extract the column names from my table. Everything works fine in mySQLWorkbench and it shows me all of my column names.

For example the output in mySQL Workbench is : nr,height,length
The output on my oracle database is: nr,height,length,nr,height,length,...

it looks like I'm in a loop, but I cant understand why. The oracle database is located at my university, so I can't get any access to work with it like mySQLWorkbench.

I tried this code below and at the moment i really dont know what to do.

```
ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null,null, tableName, null);
while(columns.next())
{ 
    String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    System.out.println(columnName + ";");
}
```

in my opinion the output should be:    nr;height;length

Comment: you may need permission to access your db located at university

Comment: I got the permissions and  I got my output (nr,height,length,nr,height,length,...) . maybe i described it a little bit wrong. my problem is only this loop output. I'm expecting every column name unique and not multiple times. columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME") works different on different databases I think